# no such table when using civicrm

Tags: database

CiviCRM 4.6.10 Joomla 3.4.0 getting this error when going to events dashboard or trying to create event.

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
DB Error: no such table
Return to home page.

Is there an sql database dump that will recreate all the civicrm databases including some expired sample data?

Answer (score 4):

Check your browser console log and check civicrm config log file after enabling the debugging and back trace. You will get more detail about this error.

Comment: this approach has worked for me; the debug/backtrace tell you which table is at fault here; for me it's always been civicrm_acl_contact_cache; once in a while it gets corrupted (not related to upgrades or anything, just happens) and I need to drop it in the d/b and copy it (just the table structure) from a backup

Answer (score 1):

In my case the missing table `jos_content`, which is an old standard name for a primary Joomla table, a name not used since many years (table name prefix is randomized).

I removed the extensions `Content Tokens` and `Fancy Tokens` and the error disappeared. (Probably the culprit was `Content Tokens` since that has CMS-specific tokens for making CMS-information available).

Answer (score 0):

For me, all that I need to do is to Empty/Flush the civicrm_acl_contact_cache table to clear the error, but it keeps coming back. Update: dropping/recreating the civicrm_acl_conact_cache no longer works for me.

Comment: Update: The missing table, in my case turned out to be the 'civicrm_mail_settings' table. Importing it from a backup appears to have resolved the 'DB Error' issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm that I had the same issue with a corrupted civicrm_acl_contact_cache table.

Dropping the table and re-importing the table structure is working for me.

Think it happen when server ran out of disk space.